# How to parallel job execution of different requests on different slaves under same label

Tags: jenkins

**In short**

How to make *one job request* distributed to *only one slave* and execute; while following job request *won't be queued* if there are other slaves idle.

**Details**

There is a service use Jenkins job as entry, user can submit request by clicking `Build Job`. At one time only one job can be executed on one slave.

To improve the throughput, I add more slaves to execute this job. However, I found following problems:

1. Use a *multi-configuration job*, the same job are spawn across over all slaves, but I only want one slave to execute the job(one request), so other slaves can execute other jobs(requests).
2. Use a *NodeLable plugin*, but when one job is executing, following jobs get queued even there are other slaves idle.

Because the entry job will trigger downstream jobs, so the slave serve the request shall not change, either another entry job can be triggered on the same slave before all the previous downstream jobs are finished.

Is there any way so the entry job picks a random slave to execute the job, meeting one user's request; and then pick another slave (if any idle) to execute another job, meeting another user's request. If all slaves are busy, coming requests will be queued and wait until a slave become idle again.

Thanks!

**What I chose**

The problem arises when different jobs depend on each other and have shared state. So to avoid future frustration, I merge all dependent jobs into one. So there are no more shared state, and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the  [Multi configuration](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project)  which comes as standard with Jenkins and allows you to run the same job with different configuration (e.g. different labels). You achieve this by creating a new job and selecting the 'Build multi-configuration project' option

Alternatively there is a [build pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin)  job which allows you to run phases of jobs in parallel

Both of these solutions are bound by the number of executors available

Comment: I want to run different request by user clicking "build job" parallel on different machine, i.e., one machine running request #1 while another running request #2. How to use Multi-configuration job to do this? I added a slave axis, but newly trigered job are distributed on all slaves instead of just one.

Comment: I see you want to have the same job run on a parameterized node, rather than the job against all labels. This might help then - I haven't used it but it looks a good candidate https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin. So you would select your node/label when starting the job

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried this plugin and it works. Now I have the workflow, but with more slaves added to execute the task, I need a entry job do the load balancing. Is there any plugin or job configuration can do this?

Comment: This might be worth a try. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Least+Load+Plugin. It could be that Jenkins by default attempts to run the build on the last one it was run on. You could also reduce the number of executors on your slaves to spread the load better. I suppose Jenkins assumes the box has capability if it has spare executors which is a reasonable assumption

Comment: Thanks again, and sorry for not make my question clearer. I've tried the NodeLabel, seems Jenkins won't allow one job to execute on multiple slaves at same time. So I think changing the load-balancing algorithm will still block the entire job even I have slaves idle.

Comment: There is an 'execute concurrent builds if necessary' checkbox on the job config page. This will change the default workspace used to add a build number on as well

Comment: Finally I merged all the jobs and checked the concurrent build, then restrict the merged job running on the label under which the slaves are.

Answer (score 1):

@Xin Huang - Add an entry "slave1 || slave2" in "Restrict where this project can be run" section.
This will make sure your job is run on any of the slaves mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) allows one job to trigger another and force it to execute on the same slave as its own run.